# How to do reverse geocoding on a node server with express+ejs

Tags: node.js, geolocation, express, reverse-geocoding, ejs

I have the latitude and longitude values. I want to display the name of the places that corresponds to those values.

I found that it can be done this way with curl.

```
http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp?lat=XXX&long=YYY&format=json
```

How can I use this in my nodejs server running express and ejs? Right now the server passes the longitude and latitude coordinates to the client, so they are available in both the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

First install [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request):

```
npm install request
```

Then:

```
var request = require('request'),
    geoUrl = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp?lat=XXX&long=YYY&format=json';

request(geoUrl, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Handling the response is up to you -- it's not really JSON, it looks more like JSONP.